# Stored procedure not returning any value when it should(MySQL)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure that I want it to return a value(the lastinsertid). All it does return is 0.
My question is what is wrong with code below?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_stored_procedure(
    IN inCartId int
)
BEGIN

    DECLARE orderId INT;

    -- Insert a new record into orders and obtain the new order ID
    INSERT INTO orders (created_on) VALUES (NOW());

    -- Obtain the new Order ID
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO orderId;

    -- Insert order details in order_detail table
    INSERT INTO order_detail (
        order_id, product_id, attributes, product_name, quantity, unit_cost
    )
    SELECT
        orderId,
        p.id,
        sc.attributes,
        p.name,
        sc.quantity,
        COALESCE( NULLIF( p.discounted_price, 0 ), p.price ) AS unit_cost
    FROM
        shopping_cart sc
        INNER JOIN products p ON sc.product_id = p.id
    WHERE
        sc.cart_id = inCartId
        AND
        sc.buy_now;

    -- Save the order's total amount
    UPDATE
        orders
    SET
        total_amount = (
            SELECT
                SUM( unit_cost * quantity )
            FROM
                order_detail
            WHERE
                order_id = orderId
        )
    WHERE
        id = orderId;

    -- Clear the shopping cart
    CALL shopping_cart_empty( inCartId );

END
```

Comment: A stored procedure’s return value is an indication of its success/failure condition and is not intended to be used to return data - for that you should use output parameters.

Comment: How can I do that @Dai

Comment: The information that you should *use output parameters* should give you enough information to use to Google *MySQL stored procedure output parameter* and make an effort to figure that out yourself, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In most database systems like MySQL/MariaDB and MS SQL Server, Stored Procedures do not have "return values" in the same way that functions do.
- Instead, stored procedures return data to their caller through **Output Parameters**.

  - In MySQL, a `FUNCTION` *does* return a value <sub>but a `FUNCTION` is different from a Stored Procedure and the explaining differences is best done in separate question</sub>.
- (In Microsoft SQL Server and Sybase, Stored Procedures do all return a single `int` 
  "return code" value, however this value is an indication of status (like how executable programs have an exit-code) and is not meant to be used to return data from your database.)
- To use Output Parameters in MySQL and MariaDB use the `OUT` keyword instead of the `IN` keyword and then assign to that parameter.

In your case, replace the local variable `orderId` with the `OUT newOrderId` parameter I've added in the stored procedure parameters list. No other changes are necessary.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_stored_procedure(
    IN inCartId int,
    OUT newOrderId int
)
BEGIN

    -- Insert a new record into orders and obtain the new order ID
    INSERT INTO orders (created_on) VALUES (NOW());

    -- Obtain the new Order ID
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO newOrderId;

    -- Insert order details in order_detail table
    INSERT INTO order_detail (
        order_id, product_id, attributes, product_name, quantity, unit_cost
    )
    SELECT
        orderId,
        p.id,
        sc.attributes,
        p.name,
        sc.quantity,
        COALESCE( NULLIF( p.discounted_price, 0 ), p.price ) AS unit_cost
    FROM
        shopping_cart sc
        INNER JOIN products p ON sc.product_id = p.id
    WHERE
        sc.cart_id = inCartId
        AND
        sc.buy_now;

    -- Save the order's total amount
    UPDATE
        orders
    SET
        total_amount = (
            SELECT
                SUM( unit_cost * quantity )
            FROM
                order_detail
            WHERE
                order_id = orderId
        )
    WHERE
        id = orderId;

    -- Clear the shopping cart
    CALL shopping_cart_empty(inCartId);

END
```